# to add "Add to cart" button at product search result

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I m using the woocommerce, and at that i want to insert the add to cart button when the search result are display. Product are displayed bt with the product name ,"Add to cart" button to available with every product at search result.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url');?>/checkout/?add-to-cart=<?php $product->id;?>">Add to cart</a>
```

use above code with your custom product id.For more details refer the link 
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/

Comment: Thanx... Bro. Bt I cancelled that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```html
<?php $id = get_the_ID(); ?>

<a href="?add-to-cart=<?php echo $id; ?>" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="59" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add “<?php the_title(); ?>” to your cart" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>
```